# How to resolve a "Error trying to create an Email Action" deployment error

Tags: deployment

When attempting to deploy a Case.sendEmail quick action we get this error message
"Error trying to create an Email Action: Error: **MISSING LABEL** PropertyFile - val SendEmailDisabled not found in section QuickActionDefinitionMessages"

How do we resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

[This Salesforce Knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000232433&language=en_US) attempts to answer that question, but only gives one part of the solution: enable "All Emails" under Email Administration > Deliverability.
The other part of the solution is mentioned in [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000194281&language=en_US): you also have to manually enable Email-to-Case in Setup.